# Using "NA" as a legitimate nonmissing value

Tags: r, na

I'm working with a data set that includes first names entered in all capital letters. I need to work with the names as character variables, not as factors.

One person in the data set has the first name "NA". Can I get `R` to accept "NA" as a legitimate character value? My work-around solution was to rename that person NAA, but I am interested to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Do you have NA values in your dataset otherwise? If not, just change the `na.strings` argument in `read.table` to something else.

Comment: `"NA"` is a character value in R and not an NA value. So just make sure that your real NA values are coded differently and take care of this during import.

Comment: Thanks to Roland and Ananda. Setting na.strings="ZZZ" in read.table takes care of my problem.

Comment: Poor ZZZ Top will be `NA` Top. :( It might be safer to use `na.strings="."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a demonstration of my comment, consider the following sample CSV file:

```
x <- tempfile()
cat("v1,v2", "NA,1", "AB,3", sep = "\n", file = x)

cat(readLines(x), sep = "\n")
# v1,v2
# NA,1
# AB,3
```

Here's the `str` of a basic `read.csv`. Note the `NA` is seen as `NA`

```
str(read.csv(x))
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ v1: Factor w/ 1 level "AB": NA 1
#  $ v2: int  1 3
```

Now, specify a different character as your `na.strings` argument:

```
str(read.csv(x, na.strings = ""))
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ v1: Factor w/ 2 levels "AB","NA": 2 1
#  $ v2: int  1 3
```

Comment: FYI `read.csv` now has a text argument: `read.csv(text = c("v1,v2", "NA,1", "AB,3"))`

Comment: @hadley, I'm very much aware of the text argument. Just demonstrating as if being read from an actual file to replicate what the OP might go through.